# next-auth errors with the credentials provider. jwt function executes twice

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, credentials, next-auth

I am using next-auth for authentication in my project. I have also augmented the session interface. Here is the code for the augmentation and the authOptions:

```
`> `declare module "next-auth" {
> interface Session extends DefaultSession {
> user: {
> id: string
> role: USER_ROLE
> active: boolean
> seller: boolean
> DefaultSession["user"]
>   }
> 
> interface User {
> role: USER_ROLE
> active: boolean
> seller: boolean
>   }
> }
> 
> export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
> adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
> providers: [
> CredentialsProvider({
> id: "credentials",
> name: "credentials",
> credentials: {
> email: {
> label: "Email",
> type: "email",
> placeholder: "abc@example.com",
>         },
>       },
> async authorize(credentials: Record<"email", string> | undefined) {
> console.log("Inside authorize function")
> if (!credentials?.email) {
> return null
>         }
> 
> const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
> where: { email: credentials.email },
>         })
> console.log("User in database", user)
> 
> if (!user) {
> console.log("No user found")
> return null
>         }
> 
> return {
> id: user.id,
> name: user.name,
> email: user.email,
> role: user.role,
> active: user.active,
> seller: user.seller,
>         }
>       },
>     }),
>   ],
> secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
> callbacks: {
> jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
> console.log("Inside jwt callback")
> console.log("User", user)
> 
> return {
>         ...token,
> id: user?.id,
> role: user?.role,
> active: user?.active,
> seller: user?.seller,
>       }
>     },
> 
> session: ({ session, user }) => {
> console.log("Inside session callback")
> console.log("User", user)
> console.log("Session", session)
> 
> return {
>         ...session,
> user: {
>           ...session.user,
> id: user.id,
> role: user.role,
> active: user.active,
> seller: user.seller,
>         },
>       }
>     },
>   },
> session: {
> strategy: "jwt",
>   },
> }``
```

Now I have 3 problems.

1. **JWEDecryptionFailed**
   When the pages in app/(lobby)/page and other folders load for the 1st time, and there is no user currently signed in, i get a JWEDecryptionFailed error saying:

> *[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
> message: 'decryption operation failed',*

I dont know why this error is generated.

2. **I am taken to /api/auth/signin?error=CredentialsSignin instead of /api/auth/signin**
   This is the code for my signIn function.

```
              <Button
                aria-label="Sign in"
                size="sm"
                onClick={() =>
                  void signIn("credentials")
                }
              >
                Sign In
              </Button>
```

When I click this button, I am taken to /api/auth/signin?error=CredentialsSignin. [I get an error in red saying: Sign in failed. Check the details you provided are correct. Even though, I did not do any signIns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUXON.png)

3. **When I myself go to /api/auth/signin**
   When I myself go to /api/auth/signin and signIn with a user's email already in the database, the authorize function runs and its logs indicate that a user has been found:

> Inside authorize function
> User in database {
> id: '1',
> name: 'John Doe',
> email: 'JohnDoes@gmail.com',
> emailVerified: 2024-01-23T10:35:37.976Z,
> password: null,
> image: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1364491704816005632/4iY6yMgX_400x400.jpg',
> role: 'USER',
> active: true,
> seller: true,
> createdAt: 2024-01-23T10:35:37.976Z,
> updatedAt: 2024-01-23T10:35:37.976Z
> }

After the logs of the authorize function, there are logs of jwt callback function as follows *but this is where things get a bit fishy*
**
My jwt callback function logs the user to the console once. But its logs 2 times:**

> Inside jwt callback
> User {
> id: '1',
> name: 'John Doe',
> email: 'JohnDoes@gmail.com',
> role: 'USER',
> active: true,
> seller: true
> }
> Inside jwt callback
> User undefined
> First log shows the correct user found in the database, but i dont why a user is consoled again and the 2nd time, the user is undefined. **The jwt function is executing twice.
> **After the 2nd log of the jwt function are the logs of the session callback function:

> Inside session callback
> User undefined
> Session {
> user: { name: 'John Doe', email: 'JohnDoes@gmail.com', image: undefined },
> expires: '2024-03-01T08:42:44.962Z'
> }

The user is undefined but the user in the session has the correct information about the user i just signed in with. Moving on, right after the session callback function I get an error saying:

*> [next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]

> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') {
> message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')",
> stack: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')\n" +
> at Object.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/lib/auth.ts:72:30
> .......
> name: 'TypeError'
> *

And after all this I am redirected back to the "/" and the page.tsx at the app/(lobby) is executed which also logs the current session and user to the console and both are null:

> Session:  null
> User in lobby layout:  undefined

They should not be null.
I hope this much information is enough to help someone debug the issue. If more info is needed please let me know. The versions of next and next-auth are:
"next": "^13.5.6",
"next-auth": "^4.24.5",